# JSON Parsing Error. String Cannot be Converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, php, android, json, parsing

I am getting the following error:

```
Error parsing to json on getJarrayFromString(); org.json.JSONException: Value result of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

My JSON Code is as follows:

```
public String getJsonFromUrl(String url){

        // to initialise the objects
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";

        //making HTTP POST request
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(DEBUG, "Error getJsonFromUrl: " + e.toString());
        }

        // Converting to String
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(DEBUG, "Error converting the response to string getJsonFromUrl: " + e.toString());
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * To convert the string recieved into json object
     * result refers to the string that will be converted
     * @return will return the json array
     */
    public JSONArray getJarrayFromString(String result){
        // Parsing string to JSON Array
        try{
            jarray = new JSONArray("result");                     <---- Error is here
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e(DEBUG, "Error parsing to json on getJarrayFromString(); " + e.toString());
        }

        return jarray;
    }
```

And My Java Activity is as follows:

```
public void onTaskCompleted(String result) {
                        try {  
                            if(result!=""){
                                // the remote php link 
                                // converting the response into json array
                                Log.i(DEBUG, result);
                                jarray = utils.getJarrayFromString(result);

                                // number of rows in total for a query
                                int mysqlSize = (jarray.getJSONObject(0).getInt("numRows"));

                                Log.i(DEBUG, "From " + from + " to " + mysqlSize);

                                // to check if all the rows are parsed from the mysql
                                if(from <= mysqlSize){
                                    int rows;
                                    // to check if there is 0
                                    if(jarray.length()>0){
                                        Log.i(DEBUG, "From " + from + " to " + Math.floor(mysqlSize/nr)*nr);
                                        if(from+5<=Math.floor(mysqlSize/nr)*nr){
                                            rows = jarray.length();
                                        }else{
                                            rows = mysqlSize%nr+1;
                                            Utils.IS_ENDED_PRODUCT_LIST = true;
                                        }
                                        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                                        for(int i=1; i<rows; i++){
                                            JSONObject row = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                            bid.add(row.getInt("bid"));
                                            bTitle.add(row.getString("bTitle"));
                                            bCode.add(row.getString("bCode"));
                                            bPrice.add(row.getString("bPrice") + "£");
                                            bDescription.add(row.getString("bDescription"));
                                            bModule.add(row.getString("bModule"));
                                            bImage.add(Utils.PATH + row.getString("bImage"));
                                            list.add(row.getString("bImage"));
                                            // to check if an id already exists in the db or to create one if doesn't exist
                                            if(!db.hasIDBooks(row.getInt("bid"))) db.createRowOnBooks(row.getInt("bid"), row.getString("bTitle"), row.getString("bCode"), row.getString("bPrice"), row.getString("bDescription"), row.getString("bModule"), Utils.PATH + row.getString("bImage"), row.getString("bSpecialOffer"), row.getInt("bSpecialDiscount"), row.getString("bDateAdded"));
                                            Log.i(DEBUG, row.getString("bDescription"));
                                        }
                                        new DownloadImages(list, bAdapter).execute();
                                    }
                                }
                                postParameters.removeAll(postParameters);
                            }else{
                                Utils.IS_ENDED_PRODUCT_LIST = true;
                                if(rlLoading.isShown()){
                                    rlLoading.startAnimation(fadeOut());
                                    rlLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {  
                            Log.e(DEBUG, "Error at fillProductList(): " + e.toString());  
                        }
                    }
                });
                task.execute();

        }else{
            // if internet connectio is not available
            // then, rows will be fetched from the local sqllite database stored on the android phone
            if(db.size(justdealsDatabase.TABLE_BOOKS) > 0){
                Cursor cursor = db.getBooksRows(justdealsDatabase.TABLE_BOOKS);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                    bid.add(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(justdealsDatabase.KEY_BID)));
                    bTitle.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(justdealsDatabase.KEY_BTITLE)));
                    bCode.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(justdealsDatabase.KEY_BCODE)));
                    bPrice.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(justdealsDatabase.KEY_BPRICE))+ "£");
                    bDescription.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(justdealsDatabase.KEY_BDESCRIPTION)));
                    bModule.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(justdealsDatabase.KEY_BMODULE)));
                    bImage.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(justdealsDatabase.KEY_BIMAGE)));
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
                bAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Utils.IS_ENDED_PRODUCT_LIST = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

FINALLY, my PHP API for above code is here:

```
 <?php
    include("MysqlConnection.php");
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $from = $_POST["from"];
    $nr = $_POST["nr"];
    // those variables are for search
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $code = $_POST["code"];
    $price = $_POST["price"];
    $module = $_POST["module"];
    $order = $_POST["order"];
    $by = $_POST["by"];


    $sql = "SET CHARACTER SET utf8";
    $db->query($sql);


        // if those 2 var are set then we order the query after them
        if(isset($order) && isset($by)){
            $sql .= " ORDER BY `$order` $by LIMIT $from, $nr";
        }else{
            $sql .= "LIMIT $from, $nr";
        }

        $query = $db->query($sql);
        $rows = array();
        $rows[] = array("numRows"=>$db->numRows($query));

        if($db->numRows($query)!=0){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $rows[] =  $row;
            }
            echo(json_encode($rows));
        }
    }

    $db->closeConnection();
?>
```

Now I have carried out an extensive research on this topic and unable to find a concrete solution to above mentioned problem.

I have read on few posts that may be strings are declared without using double quotes. Does this mean values that are stored in SQL file (eg. book name, price etc.) needs to be in double quotes rather than single quotes?

If I run the above code in JSONLint, I get the following error:

```
Parse error on line 1:

^
Expecting '{', '['
```

I tried using ("{result}") instead of {result) or ("result") but that gives me even more errors. I am so close to get this whole app work but the only problem is converting `result` string into a valid JSON Array.

Any ideas and suggestions would be highly appreciated.

EDITED LOG CAT ERRORS AFTER IMPLEMENETION JARRAY= NEW JSONARRAY (RESULT);

```
03-06 21:17:31.387: D/AndroidRuntime(818): Shutting down VM
03-06 21:17:31.387: W/dalvikvm(818): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.fokrul.justdeals.ActivityTab$ProductsAdapter.getView(ActivityTab.java:1565)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1970)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1756)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:656)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:716)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1595)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1800)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1542)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1403)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1314)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1542)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1403)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1314)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1282)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2040)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-06 21:17:31.417: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you have _any_ output before the `echo(json_encode`? Whitespace, BOM marks, etc?

Comment: `jarray = new JSONArray("result"); ` ... why yes, the `String` literal "result" certainly isn't a JSON array. You also don't use `!=` to compare `String` objects in java. Java is not a scripting language.

Comment: What happens when you try to access the php file directly in a browser? i see an extra `}` which leads me to suspect you are actually getting errors instead of json ouput (or you are cutting out some code)

Comment: @Wrikken there isn't any output before `echo statement`
@BrianRoach I didn't get that. Are you saying that I shouldn't be using "result", if I use just (result), Log Cat shows more than 15 errors including a fatal exception and application crashes automatically!!!

Comment: @datasage If I try that php in my browser. I get absolutely NOTHING but a blank white screen!

Comment: Your current code is not outputing anything in the case of 0 results. You should output an empty array at least. Also in testing it via browser, you may want to switch `$_POST` to `$_REQUEST` to allow you to post vars via url parameters.

Comment: @datasage in that case it produces NULL on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This portion here

```
jarray = new JSONArray("result");
```

should of course read

```
jarray = new JSONArray(result);
```

instead, but I guess you've already tried that. Judging from the parser error, I assume that *result* simply does not contain a valid JSON string. If it should represent an array, it would have to be something like this (in its simplest form):

```
["abc", "def", "ghi"]
```

Some JSON parsers are picky when it comes to single or double quotes. But it seems that in your case the problem is rather with the brackets. Could you please step into *getJarrayFromString* using the debugger and check what the value of *result* is that goes into *getJarrayFromString* or maybe at least print the raw value to the console?

Comment: Thanks @alexander.biskop 
What exactly needs to be done? What statement do I need to add to log output? I am sorry but I am pretty new to this stuff. Appreciated your help mate.

Comment: I was about to say: You could add a Log.i(...); statement as you already have them in other places in the code. Then I realized there is already a log statement right before your call to getJarrayFromString - there it says  Log.i(DEBUG, result); . So actually, you should already be able to see what is happening in your log.

Comment: That's the thing. I am only getting this error in the log `03-06 21:17:29.417: E/JustDealsUtils(818): Error parsing to json on getJarrayFromString(); org.json.JSONException: Value Database of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Comment: Please see above for edited Error Log Cat If I use `jarray = new JSONArray(result); 
Can there be errors if Images have larger file size? as above errors might suggest some out of memory errors. Each image is around 14.5KB each..

Comment: You probably can't see anything else in the log because the log level is set to ERROR or something, and DEBUG infos are not being logged. For the time being, change Log.i(DEBUG, result); to Log.e(DEBUG, result); so that you can see it in the log file.

Comment: Could it be that the value of *result* is actually *Database* (which of course is garbage and therefore cannot be parsed as a JSON array)?

Comment: Then in that case, what do I need to change in my database? Did you managed to look at the updated log above? Thanks again